# How to make a crossed out \leftrightarrow?

Tags: arrows

I want to make a `\leftrightarrow` that is crossed out on both sided arrows. It can be crossed out separately or in a single slash either is fine. I tried doing a `\stackrel` on `\nleftarrow` and `\nrightarrow` yielding disproportionate results. Thank you for help in advances.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you tried and a manual sketch of what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,centernot}
\newcommand*\crampedhalign[1]{%
    \vcenter{%
        \baselineskip=0pt
        \lineskip=0pt
        \halign{$\mathsurround=0pt##$\crcr#1\crcr}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*\nrightleftarrows{\mathrel{\crampedhalign{\nrightarrow\cr\nleftarrow\cr}}}
\newcommand*\nleftrightarrows{\mathrel{\crampedhalign{\nleftarrow\cr\nrightarrow\cr}}}
\begin{document}
$\centernot\leftrightarrows$
$\centernot\rightleftarrows$
$\nleftrightarrows$
$\nrightleftarrows$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Ti*k*Z solution. The `\raisebox` is used to make the symbols perfectly centered vertically.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\doubleCross}{%
    \raisebox{-1pt}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.2]%
            \draw [->] (0, 0) -- (0.25, 0);         % Right arrow           
            \draw [<-] (0, 0.1) -- (0.25, 0.1);     % Left arrow
            \draw [black](0.25,0.15) -- (0,-0.05);  % Cross on both arrows
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
}

\newcommand{\singleCross}{%
    \raisebox{-1pt}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.2]%
            \draw [<-] (0, 0) -- (0.25, 0);             % Left arrow
            \draw [black](0.16,0.15) -- (0.08,0.05);    % Left arrow cross
            \draw [->] (0, 0.1) -- (0.25, 0.1);         % Right arrow 
            \draw [black](0.16,0.05) -- (0.08,-0.05);   % Right arrow cross
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    This is the \verb|\doubleCross| \doubleCross symbol. 
    This is the \verb|\singleCross| \singleCross symbol.
\end{document}
```